# Drupal 7.53 pathauto pattern field do not transliterate

Tags: path-aliases

I created a new field in on a content type I have on my application (Drupal 7.53), then in /admin/config/search/path/patterns I have set a pattern to this type of content as the following:

[node:field-nw-sitemap:0:url:path]/[node:field_titulo_url].

I expected to have a result like:

**mysite/subpath/new-content**
it works fine on development environment, but in homolog, witch is online, the return to the url is 
**mysite/subpath/New%20Content**.
Has anyone been here before? Help please. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal answers. This issue sounds like a bug in the module, which you should report in the module's issue queue so it can be fixed. This is not the right place for bug reports. Some times it's late in the process you actually find out that the problem is a bug in the module and not something you did wrong.

Comment: Anyways, closing this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Drupal issue queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested several times and looked all over the internet, in one test I was able to reproduce the problem in dev environment. The problem was that the filed name contained the keyword "url", the problem persisted with the word "path", once I changed the field machine name to field_caminho everything worked fine.